# How to remove spaces between two characters in php?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace spaces with hyphens in a string like this:

```
"mauris pellentesque^elementum pulvinar etiam non quam^sit amet".
```

What I want is to replace all spaces only in the range between the two ^ characters including the ^ characters:

```
"mauris pellentesque-elementum-pulvinar-etiam-non-quam-sit amet".
```

I'm using the following code, but it only removes the last space, could you please help me to fix it:

```
preg_replace("'\*(.+) (.+)\*'is", "$1-$2", $string);
```

Comment: Well not really a complete solution but could work if there is only cases where max 2 `^` exists. " (?=.*\^)(?!.*\^.*\^)" ,replace with `-`.

Comment: I got the following result: mauris pellentesque^-e-l-e-m-e-n-t-u-m- -p-u-l-v-i-n-a-r- -e-t-i-a-m- -n-o-n- -q-u-a-m-^sit amet

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I want the ^ characters to be removed as well, I will edit my question.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0fgOWA/3 Note: will only work if there is exactly 2 `^`.

Comment: That's strange, somehow it translates differently in PHP, I will try to sort it out. Anyway, it's perfect thanks. you could add it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$s = "mauris pellentesque^elementum pul^vinar etiam no^n quam^sit amet ^bla bla^ bla okok yes";

$parts = explode('^', $s);
$count = count($parts);

if ($count >= 3 && $count % 2 == 1) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
        $parts[$i] = str_replace(' ', '-', $parts[$i]);
    }
    $s = implode($parts);
}

var_dump($s);
```

See [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Nice solution, though it doesn't work for me because the string might have more than 1 repetition: so I will have to make many explode and it will be pretty complicated.

Comment: @Tarek.hms more than 1 repetition of what? If you will have more than one pair of `^...^` then you ought have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @Tarek.hms Hi, see the update answer, maybe what's you need. The code get uglier of course. But of course if the regex solution works for you it's ok.

Comment: I prefer the regex. Thanks anyway.